# CSS with large div translate animation with will-change still has high CPU usage in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I made a css infinite marquee animation copied from [this codepen](https://codepen.io/nickcil/pen/BygPMY).

[My codepen](https://codepen.io/Knovour/pen/boJNPN)

In Google Chrome, the CPU useage is about 15% ~ 25%.

[image]

But it cause 55% ~ 80% CPU usage in Firefox (both stable and developer edition) with this animation.

[image]

[image]

My Macbook hardware (cpu, memory, graphic card)

[image]

It seems nothing different by using `will-change` or `translate3d`. Any solution?

Comment: Did you try `backface-visibility:hidden`? (hacky and should be avoided but helps determine if the issue can be solved with hardware acceleration)

Comment: @Ihazkode It seems nothing different. :(

Comment: I have similar progress with marquee. On Chrome I have ~4% CPU and on Firefox ~20%...